# How to show dropdown in excel using jrxml (jasper api)?

Tags: jasper-reports, apache-poi, export-to-excel, dropdown

I am new to jasper . My project used jasper to create  an excel template that has only column names (eg : Name , Age , Department , Location) which uses jrxml for fonts and alignment. [basically we used the  for showing the column names]

User can download the template and they can enter the values they want.

Now in  order to avoid user enter the details manually by entering values , I would like to give dropdowns in the template with some hard coded values .

For example for the field 'Location' , I can set values like 'Texas' , 'California', 'FortWorth' etc . I am not querying from DB for these values , I just want to hard code these in .jrxml . I have to create one more row where the Location column alone should have drop down values from which user can pick one and upload to my application

In the downloaded excel , I want a dropdown with the above values so that user can select instead of typing themselves.

Is there any way to put this in .jrxml . If that is not possible then give the code that can render these in a dropdown in excel.

My sample .jrxml for one field is

```
<staticText>
    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="684" y="0" width="114" height="20" backcolor="#808080">
    </reportElement>
    <box leftPadding="10">
        <pen lineColor="#000000" />
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" />
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" />
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" />
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" />
    </box>
    <textElement>
        <font size="10" isBold="true" />
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[Location]]></text>
</staticText>
```

Please let me know if more details are required

Comment: Hi Robert, I read that article but I am not using jasper or iReports in my application . I have jasperreport.jar and jrxml in my application . so I am not able to get an equivalent code in jrxml that will display a combo box in excel

Comment: Petter Friberg it will be great if you can share the template example where I can bring the combobox with values hardcoded in the template itself. I am eagerly awaiting for the template

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that with current jasper api 6.0 this is possibile but with **POI** (that is already in your classpath) it is farily easy to add this after export.

First we export or `JasperPrint` `print`, to excel (include code since its best to remove empty rows, we will process with poi later, `Exception` handling is beyond this example)

```
JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
File outputFile = new File("excelTest.xls");
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputFile));
SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
configuration.setCollapseRowSpan(false);
configuration.setWhitePageBackground(false);
configuration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenColumns(true);
configuration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Now that the report is exported to **excel**, we re-open it with POI and **add** our **data validation**.

```
int rowCount = 50; //This will be discussed at end.
int cellWithDV = 1;

HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(outputFile));
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1,rowCount, cellWithDV, cellWithDV);
DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(
                    new String[]{ "Texas" , "California", "FortWorth"});
DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, dvConstraint);
dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
workbook.close();
```

The `rowCount` can be achived by:

1. Querying the database again
2. Use a scriptlet that counts how many times beforeDetailEval() is called
3. Use POI to find the the last row.
4. Use maximum value in excel (2003) is 65536

Hope this helps

Comment: It answered my  question . Thanks