# Java: How to display barcode in excel sheet?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I am trying to display **barcode in excel sheet** using API's like Apache POI but didn't found any solution.

I also tried using JasperReports (as we can generate barcode in it) and then convert the compiled report to excel using `JRXlsExporter`.

Below is my **jrxml** for the excel export

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="customer_export" language="groovy" pageWidth="755" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="715" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
<parameter name="siteId" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="companyId" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT c.NAME ,c.EXTERNAL_CODE ,a.ADDRESS,CASE  WHEN c.LOCAL_MAIL IS NOT NULL THEN c.LOCAL_MAIL when C.MAIL IS NOT NULL then c.MAIL when c.MAIL IS Null then NULL when c.LOCAL_MAIL is NULL then NULL ELSE NULL END as MAIL, ru.BARCODE, c.PHONE FROM CUSTOMER c, SITE csite, RACK_USER ru, ADDRESS a WHERE c.COMPANY_SITE_ID = csite.ID_SITE AND c.RACK_USER_ID = ru.ID_RACK_USER AND ru.ID_RACK_USER = a.RACK_USER_ID AND csite.ID_SITE=$P{companyId} AND c.SITE_ID=$P{siteId} AND a.MAIN_FOR_COMPANY_SITE=1 AND a.COMPANY_SITE_ID =$P{companyId} ORDER BY c.NAME ASC]]>
</queryString>
<field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="EXTERNAL_CODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="ADDRESS" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="MAIL" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="BARCODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="PHONE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<title>
    <band height="20">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="119" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Customer Name]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="119" y="0" width="112" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Customer Code]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="231" y="0" width="157" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="388" y="0" width="121" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Email]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="509" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Barcode]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="609" y="0" width="106" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Phone Number]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<detail>
    <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="119" height="24"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="119" y="0" width="112" height="24"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EXTERNAL_CODE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="231" y="0" width="157" height="24"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ADDRESS}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="388" y="0" width="121" height="24"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MAIL}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="609" y="0" width="106" height="24"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PHONE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="509" y="0" width="100" height="24"/>
            <jr:barbecue xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="Code39" drawText="true" checksumRequired="false" evaluationTime="Report">
                <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA["1234"]]></jr:codeExpression>
            </jr:barbecue>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
```

**Java** code to export excel:

```java
JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jprint);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, reportos);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.MAXIMUM_ROWS_PER_SHEET, 50000);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, filename);
exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

But in **Barcode column** I'm getting **empty** when excel is exported.

Is there any attribute I need to apply in JasperReports or in Java or anything else?

Or is there any other API's or can we display barcode using Apache POI?

Comment: Hi! Have you tried to add it as a picture?

Comment: Thanks for reply.
No. I would like to do it by java code or if possible by jasperReport. if your thinking it by code or anything like that then please let me know.

Comment: @techGaurdian I have posted an answer how you can generate barcode as image (Image), this you can use in both poi and in jasper-reports. A small note your java code is a deprecated way of setting parameters, see for example this answer [JRXlsExporter usage example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33628651/5292302) for non deprecated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [barcode4j](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/) or [barbecue](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/) you can generate the barcode as an image in java and then pass it to jasper-reports

### Example with barcode4j

**Java code**

```
public class MyBarcodeGenerator {
  public static Image getGS1_128(String code) {
    if (code==null){
        return null;
    }
    EAN128Bean c = new EAN128Bean();
    c.setChecksumMode(ChecksumMode.CP_AUTO);
    c.setOmitBrackets(false);
    c.setCodeset(Code128Constants.CODESET_C);
    c.setMsgPosition(HumanReadablePlacement.HRP_BOTTOM);
    c.doQuietZone(true);
    c.setQuietZone(5);
    c.setFontSize(2d);
    
    int dpi = 200;
    boolean antiAlias = false;
    int orientation = 0;
    BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = new BitmapCanvasProvider(dpi, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, antiAlias, orientation);
    c.generateBarcode(canvas, code);
    return canvas.getBufferedImage();
  }
}
```

**jrxml, displaying the image**

```xml
<image scaleImage="Clip" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" isUsingCache="false" onErrorType="Blank">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="112" y="67" width="315" height="95" uuid="b90b1ec8-1483-4677-8db4-4556ecdad6b3">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{GS1_128}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[my.package.MyBarcodeGenerator.getGS1_128($F{GS1_128})]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

> For correct image size change the dpi settings or use the batik libraries to generate svg images, it's a bit more complex but with much better resolution see [barcode4j svg dom](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/svg-dom.html)

Comment: thanks for reply. Will modify the code for JRXlsExporter.
But i'm getting error while exporting....
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
 Source text : com.web.util.BarcodeGenerator.getGS1_128($F{BARCODE})
also
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: com for class: customer_export_1464845996642_768750

Comment: if i change the jasper report language from groovy to java... i get the below error during compile time....
com.web.util.BarcodeGenerator cannot be resolved to a type.
BarcodeGenerator.getGS1_128($F{BARCODE})

Comment: Also can alphanumerical barcode (eg. F123456) work ?
just asking i'm getting ...java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to read AI: Characters must be numerical!

Comment: You need to set your class in classpath of jasper report, in the example I was using the [GS1-128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1-128) barcode it as has it own specific usage  (I don't know what barcode you need)

Comment: @techGaurdian Sorry I did not see your pings (I'm active in chat rooms see profile so just to many pings sometimes) If you just need any barcode to also supports text you can use Code39 or Code128 (Code128Bean), if you still need help ping me in one of the rooms

Comment: no problem. will try setting classpath first. and yes if i need any help will surely ping u. Thanks :)

Comment: nope.. i tried with JasperReport but was not working...as i was getting compile error (using barcode Code39)(we could chat about the error). Another i tried with Apache POI with adding picture of barcode in excel and it worked but as it was picture it was static i wanted a dynamic barcode like in jasperReport. For now i'm using select box by which user can select PDF or EXCEL format for the export.. PDF using JasperReport with barcode and EXCEL only barcode number... BUT will like to implement Barcode in EXCEL...so we can chat :)

Comment: @techGaurdian I'm in this room [SOCVFinder](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/socvfinder) or the SOCVR room just ping me.